# How to plot a correlation chart in Python?

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

I want to plot a correlation chart between variables "BTC" and "B3" similar to this one here:

https://charts.coinmetrics.io/correlations/

Can anyone point me some material where I can study how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and matplotlib are libraries that address your needs, see their docs related to your use case:

https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html#numpy.correlate

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/index.html

These are well known and widely used but they are not part of Python standard library.

Some would use also pandas, but IMHO it is not needed here at all.

Also you would like to load your data into your app. Use something like csv in standard library. Or use requests and json if you can call some API to get your data.

Answer (score 0):

To plot a correlation chart in Python:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = ['id1','id2','id3','id4']
y1 = [3,5,6,2]
y2 = [4,2,5,1]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(y1, y2)

for i, txt in enumerate(l):
    ax.annotate(txt, (y1[i], y2[i]))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can I make it a line plot?

Comment: You ask for a correlation chart. Correlation chart can not be a line plot.

Comment: Oh, I thought it could be. Could you please check the link I posted in the question? They made a line correlation chart. That's what I need to do.

Comment: It is not a correlation chart. It is just a line chart. Still, replace ax.scatter by ax.plot in my code and you'll have it.